# Add target=_blank on all link occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add a target="_blank" on all occurrences of the href tag in a string, using javascript inside a function?

For example:

input string:

```
var input = 'this is a test string <a href="https://example.com" ui-link="https://example.com">example</a>, and this is another test string <a href="http://example2.com">example 2</a>.'

var output = convertString(input);

output should equal: 'this is a test string <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com" ui-link="https://example.com">example</a>, and this is another test string <a target="_blank" href="http://example2.com">example 2</a>.'
```

Comment: i would convert to ast, transform the tree, then re-stringify it

Comment: Do you really need to store the HTML into a `var` ?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting it from the backend, need to change it to add the target blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace '

```js
var input = 'this is a test string <a href="https://example.com" ui-link="https://example.com">example</a>, and this is another test string <a href="http://example2.com">example 2</a>';

function convertString(input){
  return input.split('<a').join('<a target="_blank"')
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(convertString(input)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple quick and dirty solution:

```
function convert(str) {
    const a_tag = /<a (.*)>/g;
    return str.replace(a_tag, '<a target="_blank" $1>');
}
```

The regex uses a capture group to hold onto the various existing attributes of the tag and pipe them into the replacement string at the position of `$1`.

[demo](https://repl.it/L2Lv)